# Solving DFT of this array

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

I am told to solve the DFT of the following array

(5,5,5,5)

However, according to the answer sheet, it is suppose to be (5,0,0,0). I tried working it out by hand, and F(0) was correct. But my subsequent F(1)..etc. were all wrong. Where am i going wrong

[image]

Comment: Hint: A DFT corresponds to multiplying the input vector $[5,5,5,5]$ in your case) by the (symmetric) DFT matrix, whose $(m,n)$-th element is $\frac 1N e^{i2\pi mn/N}$. (Note: rows and columns are numbered from $0$ to $N-1$. Can you first calculate the $4\times 4$ DFT matrix (SubHint: the first row and column are $[\frac 14, \frac 14, \frac 14, \frac 14]$) _without_ using cosines and sines anywhere?

Comment: I think your issue arises when you evaluate $-j\sin \left( \frac{6 \pi}{4} \right)$, hint it's not equal to $1$ but equal to...

Comment: But sin(6pi/4) = -1. Hence, the sign flips it and it becomes j. Ah ic

Comment: Dilip, how can i avoid having to calculate all the sins and cosines. it is taking too much time and i will definitely fail my exam if i do this. Also, as you can see it is very easy to make careless mistakes

Comment: @user1436508 hrm you still seem to be missing something, $-j\sin \left( \frac{6 \pi}{4} \right) = -j \sin \left( \frac{3 \pi}{2} \right) = -j (-1) = j$ so in the end we get $\frac{5}{4}(j-j) = 0$

Comment: Yup, managed to solve it. Still, is there an easier way to solve this. if i do this, it will take almost 10 mins to solve every question.

Comment: @user1436508 well, memorizing roots of unity helps, otherwise not much you can do (unless you're interested in acting like a computer and memorizing fast fourier transform algorithms)